# Page speed scans site multiple times

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insight scaning my site twice. I have asked in wordpress and my theme forums they said its not a bug.

I have deleted cookies and page cache from server and wp rocket.
The only plugins activated are yoast,wp rocket and imagfy.
I have reinstalled all.and still see the same result.

Here is the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/R00LXMY) and this is the [website](https://koctaksi.com/)

Any idea why ?

Comment: When i test i dont see this issue using pagespeed insights or lighthouse in google chrome. Can you confirm both links are https: ? Maybe if there was a mix of http and https could happen not sure. Or different plugins enqueue same script ?

Comment: @Snuffy Just same as wp forum, they said the same. but I see the same result on pc and mobile on 3 different ip's. Dont know why.

Comment: Try with gtmetrix and see if the results are the same.

Comment: I tried gtmetrix and got the same result, tought its a bug, answer cleared it thanks.

Comment: I think your issue is the preload content - https://prnt.sc/BiZBD3d-_YIj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That audit is not saying it's loading the same resource twice. It's saying that JavaScript file is causing two long tasks:

[image: English screenshot of the audit]

The same JavaScript file can create many long tasks. For example it might execute several bits of slow JavaScript. Or the same bit of slow JavaScript every so often.

Other audits (for example the "JavaScript Execution time" audit) show the total per script:

[image: JavaScript Execution time]

You can get more details if you run a Lighthouse trace in DevTools and use DevTools throttling:

[image: DevTools throttling]

You will see it similarly shows a number (4 this time) long tasks:

[image: 4 long tasks]

And then click on View Trace:

[image: View Treemap and View Trace buttons]

it will load the trace in the Performance Panel:

[image: View Trace with 4 long tasks]

There are indeed 4 long tasks (as shown with the red triangles). You can dig into this more there.

Comment: So, is that just a information not a bug right ? its not happening in my php created sites just in wp lol

Comment: Correct. It's like if you have two coffees in a cafe and it lists them both in your receipt. It doesn't mean there are cafes (two scripts), or even that you visited the cafe twice (the same script loaded twice). It's just saying you had two coffees when you visited that cafe (the same script resulted in two long tasks).